# Why my ASUS BIOS detects and runs Kingston DDR4 3200MHz memory as 2400MHz?

Tags: memory, bios, motherboard, speed, ddr

In my new computer there are 2x8Gb Kingston Fury DDR 4 (Kingston kf432c16bb1k2/16) modules.
Still ASUS Prime Z590-A with Intel i5 11600-K detects it as 2400MHz. Modules installed according ASUS recommendation to A2, B2 slot.

I've installed and ran Passmark RamMon, which confirmes the modules as 3200MHz, but also writes in the Timings section 2400Mz...

**Question**

I do not know is this some BIOS setup mistake, or error either in mobo or RAM modules. or am I missing something.

[image]

[image]

[image]